# What PDF viewer will allow me to quickly view which elements are vector?

Tags: windows, pdf, vector-graphics

I work in the printing industry where having vector artwork for a job is paramount when it comes to the best production output. Often times clients will send me a PDF file that contains a raster image rather than the vector format I need.

The first thing I do when I open an image file in Adobe Illustrator is I view it in Outline move to examine what is vector and what is not. You can see the difference below

**View → Preview**:

[image: Preview viewing mode]

**View → Outline**:

[image: Outline viewing mode]

Since you can see all the "lines" of the artwork, it's easy to confirm that this artwork is 100% vector.

I don't always have Illustrator available to me, so I'm looking for a PDF viewer (either browser based or stand-alone is fine) that can replicate this functionality. Is there any such software that can help with this workflow?

Comment: Quick'n dirty workaround: zoom in to that pdf and see if it pixelates.

Comment: @Olli that is essentially what I do now, but the embedded image can sometimes be a high enough resolution that it does not pixelate, even at the maximum zoom level

Comment: @JohnB, what budget? $$$ or $$$$$?

Comment: @Pacerier I no longer need this as part of my workflow, but don't let cost prevent you from providing an answer if you know of one!

Answer (score 6):

It's not a PDF Viewer, but if you don't have Illustrator available, you might be able to use the same steps in the [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/en/) vector graphics editor.  Inkscape is free and open source.  There's also a [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/inkscape_portable) that you could carry around on a flash drive.

There are several ways that you could reasonably do this in Inkscape:

1. InkScape has the same Outline / Wire-frame mode that Illustrator has - find it in `View` → `DisplayMode` → `Outline`
2. You can use the command line to export the PDF as SVG and look for embedded non-SVG images.  From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084742/extracting-vector-graphics-from-pdf-with-inkscape:

   ```
   inkscape --without-gui --file=input.pdf --export-plain-svg=output.svg
   ```

[image: An image in Inkscape]

Comment: And it does support PDF? OP explicitly stated that's a requirement: *clients will send me a PDF file* [...] *I'm looking for a PDF viewer* – should be clear enough, no? Don't get me wrong, Inkscape is great. But it's not fitting the requirements here (or you missed to point out how it does).

Comment: @Izzy It looks like it *does* support PDF import. See http://inkscape.org/en/learn/faq/#What_formats_can_Inkscape_import.2Fexport.3F

Comment: @MosheKatz just checked: Yes, indeed – thanks! In that case, the second part of my "or condition" is met: *missed to point out how it does*. I rarely use Inkscape. The questioner might not even know it. So OK, it imports PDF; but how to tell what's vector and what not? How does it meet the requirements specified?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is probably just to export the images from the PDF and see what kind of images you get.  I have used [PDFMate PDF Converter](http://www.pdfmate.com/pdf-converter-free.html) (free; make sure to uncheck installation of adware in the installer though) for this in the past.  All you need to do is to make sure that "Extract all images in PDF files" is selected in the "Advanced Options" window.

Alternatively, you could convert the PDF to an SVG (using Inkscape as mentioned in the other answer or using any other tool) and run [this Python script](https://github.com/denilsonsa/small_scripts/blob/master/extract_embedded_images_from_svg.py) to extract the images.

Comment: For *nix users, the equivalent is `pdfimages`, one of the [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) utilities.